# An iOS game using MVC, should the model has objRect while keeping its UIViewImage object in the ViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, uikit

A game on iOS is using this: there is a metal ball, and the `ballRect` is a property of the Model class, but the corresponding `ball` which is a `UIImageView object`, is a property of the `ViewController` class.

Can this design be made so that both `ballRect` and `ball` are properties of the Model class?  In other game sample, I see only 2 properties of the `ViewController` class: the model object and a timer object.  That's it.  I wonder why this time, there are extra properties that become the `ViewController` class and should they go to the Model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to make a BallView that holds a pointer to a Ball (Model) and hosts an image view that shows the ball sprite. The BallView should observe the Ball's `ballRect`, and when that changes, update its (the BallView's) `frame` to match.

This arrangement would let you add other, similar relationships. For example, if there are different kinds of balls and a ball can change from one kind to another (e.g., for a temporary power-up), the BallView can observe the Ball's `kind` and change the image view's `image` whenever the Ball's `kind` changes.

Comment: so `BallView` should belong to the `ViewController` class or `GameModel` class?

Comment: @動靜能量: It should be a new class entirely.

Comment: new class entirely... but part of the ViewController or GameModel class?

Comment: @動靜能量: A new separate class cannot be part of another class.

Comment: if it is a new class, do you instantiate it?  If you do, do you use an instance variable in some class(es) to reference it?  (part of a class's attributes)

Comment: @動靜能量: A class you don't instantiate might as well not exist; you have to create an instance of it for it to serve some purpose in your program (particularly true of views, since you can only add instances to the view hierarchy). The ways to refer to an object are listed in the Objective-C document.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on gamasutra for applying the MVC pattern in games.
It is coded in C++, but you can easily transfer the concepts to any other language.

I hope it is of use for you.

http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/IvicaAracic/20100919/88083/Applying_the_ModelViewController_Pattern.php

Regards,
Ivica